# How to Calculate values on Check of CheckBox (Gridview Header and in row)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting problem when I do check on Header check box,Below is my Gridview which i bind from c# not by jquery Ajax

> First Scenario :IF Header is Check - AMT calculate is proper
>
> Second  : when uncheck AMT cleared properly
>
> Third : when multiple row check box is checked manually i.e. one by one and
>   then i uncheck any one row and then I check header checkbox ,AMOUNT
>   getting calucated is wrong ?

I am having Issue in Header Check.Logic failed in this part.

Here is my table look like

[image]

So Far what I did is :

```
$("[id*=chkHeader]").live("click", function () {
            debugger;
            var chkHeader = $(this);
            var grid = $(this).closest("table");
            $("input[type=checkbox]", grid).each(function (i) {
                if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");

                    if (i >= 1) {
                        if (isNaN($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val()) && isNaN($('[id*= txtcodex]').val())) {
                            $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
                            $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(totalCodex.toFixed(2));
                        } else {
                           /* if (grid[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[i].cells[4].firstElementChild.checked != true) {*/
                                //$('#ctl00_hldPage_txttcfsa').val(0);
                                //$('#ctl00_hldPage_txtcodex').val(0);

                                TCFSA = $('[id*= lbtcfsa]').html();
                                totalPrice = parseFloat(TCFSA);
                                Codex = $('[id*= lbcodex]').html();
                                totalCodex = parseFloat(Codex);
                                EarlierTCFSAValue = parseFloat($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val());
                                EarlierCodexAValue = parseFloat($('[id*= txtcodex]').val());

                                    TCFSTotalBal = parseFloat(EarlierTCFSAValue) + parseFloat(totalPrice);
                                    CodexTotalBal = parseFloat(EarlierCodexAValue) + parseFloat(totalCodex);

                                $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(TCFSTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                                $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(CodexTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                            }
                        }

                   /* }*/
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr("checked");


                        if (isNaN($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val()) && isNaN($('[id*= txtcodex]').val())) {
                            $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
                            $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(totalCodex.toFixed(2));
                        } else {
                            TCFSAAmtRemaning = 0;
                            CodexAmtRemaning = 0;
                            $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(TCFSAAmtRemaning.toFixed(2));
                            $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(CodexAmtRemaning.toFixed(2));
                        }

                }
            });


        });
        $("[id*=chkRow]").live("click", function () {
            debugger;
            var grid = $(this).closest("table");
            var chkHeader = $("[id*=chkHeader]", grid);
            if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
                chkHeader.removeAttr("checked");

                TCFSA = $('[id*= lbtcfsa]').html();
                minusprice = parseFloat(TCFSA);
                Codex = $('[id*= lbcodex]').html();
                minusCodex = parseFloat(Codex);

                if ((isNaN($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val())) && isNaN($('[id*= txtcodex]').val())) {
                    $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(minusprice.toFixed(2));
                    $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(minusCodex.toFixed(2));

                }
                else {
                    TCFSAAmtRemaning = parseFloat($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val());
                    TCFSAAmtRemaning = parseFloat(TCFSAAmtRemaning);
                    CodexAmtRemaning = parseFloat($('[id*= txtcodex]').val());
                    CodexAmtRemaning = parseFloat(CodexAmtRemaning);
                    TCFSAAmtRemaning = TCFSAAmtRemaning - minusprice;
                    CodexAmtRemaning = CodexAmtRemaning - minusCodex;

                    $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(TCFSAAmtRemaning.toFixed(2));
                    $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(CodexAmtRemaning.toFixed(2));
                }


            } else {
                if ($("[id*=chkRow]", grid).length == $("[id*=chkRow]:checked", grid).length) {
                    chkHeader.attr("checked", "checked");

                    TCFSA = $('[id*= lbtcfsa]').html();
                    totalPrice = parseFloat(TCFSA);
                    Codex = $('[id*= lbcodex]').html();
                    totalCodex = parseFloat(Codex);
                    EarlierTCFSAValue = parseFloat($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val());
                    EarlierCodexAValue = parseFloat($('[id*= txtcodex]').val());
                    TCFSTotalBal = parseFloat(EarlierTCFSAValue) + parseFloat(totalPrice);
                    CodexTotalBal = parseFloat(EarlierCodexAValue) + parseFloat(totalCodex);
                    $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(TCFSTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                    $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(CodexTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                }
                else {
                    TCFSA = $('[id*= lbtcfsa]').html();
                    totalPrice = parseFloat(TCFSA);
                    Codex = $('[id*= lbcodex]').html();
                    totalCodex = parseFloat(Codex);
                    if (isNaN($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val()) && isNaN($('[id*= txtcodex]').val())) {
                        $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
                        $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(totalCodex.toFixed(2));
                    } else {

                        TCFSTotalBal = ($('[id*= txttcfsa]').val());
                        TCFSTotalBal = parseFloat(TCFSTotalBal);
                        CodexTotalBal = parseFloat($('[id*= txtcodex]').val());
                        CodexTotalBal = parseFloat(CodexTotalBal);
                        TCFSTotalBal = parseFloat(TCFSTotalBal) + parseFloat(totalPrice);
                        CodexTotalBal = CodexTotalBal + totalCodex;

                        $('[id*= txttcfsa]').val(TCFSTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                        $('[id*= txtcodex]').val(CodexTotalBal.toFixed(2));
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Hers is my aspx Design

```
 <asp:GridView ID ="grd_cfs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TCFSA" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-color">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbtcfsa" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TCFSA")%>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CODEX" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-color">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbcodex" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CODEX")%>'></asp:Label>

                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header-color" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" />
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView >

 <asp:TextBox ID ="txttcfsa" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID ="txtcodex" runat="server" >
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle of your code, so it's easy to debugg..

Comment: are you using jquery 1.7 or lower?

Comment: `if (chkHeader.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).attr("checked", "checked");` ca you explain this?

Comment: It wil check header checkbox.$(this) is refernce to header checkbox

Comment: and the second line when you check all the options?

Comment: When header checkbox is checked all the row checkbox will also get Checked.and if any row checkbox is unchecked in that case header checkbox will also get unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code. There are two events you need to handle.

1. When rows checkboxes are changed: find all the checkboxes that are checked and sum the values from the two columns
2. When header checkboxes are changed: set all row checkboxes to header's state, then trigger event for row change

Here's a running snippet:

```js
//event handler for row clicks
$(".chkRow").on("change", function() {
  var totaltcfsa = 0;
  var totalcodex = 0;

  //loop through each checked row and sum the different columns
  $(".chkRow:checked").each(function() {
    var chk = $(this);
    var tcfsa = chk.parent().siblings(":nth-child(3)").text();
    var codex = chk.parent().siblings(":nth-child(4)").text();
    totaltcfsa += parseFloat(tcfsa);
    totalcodex += parseFloat(codex);
  });

  //display results
  $("#totaltcfsa").val(totaltcfsa.toFixed(2));
  $("#totalcodex").val(totalcodex.toFixed(2));
});

//event handler for header click
$("#chkHeader").on("change", function() {
  var checked = this.checked;

  //set all rows to the same as the header
  $(".chkRow").prop("checked", checked);

  //trigger row changed event
  $(".chkRow").trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>CFS Name</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>TCFSA</th>
    <th>CODEX</th>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="chkHeader"/></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRANSWORLD GLS INDIA</td>
    <td>2000.00</td>
    <td>1420.00</td>
    <td>580.00</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkRow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRANSWORLD GLS INDIA</td>
    <td>2000.00</td>
    <td>1420.00</td>
    <td>580.00</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkRow"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TRANSWORLD GLS INDIA</td>
    <td>2000.00</td>
    <td>1420.00</td>
    <td>580.00</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkRow"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
Total TCFSA <input id="totaltcfsa" />
Total Codex <input id="totalcodex" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of you have add id in every TD, and write below query,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  $("[id*=chkHeader]").live("click", function () {    
           $("[id*=txttcfsa]").val($(".lbtcfsa", $(this).closest("tr")).html());    
           $("[id*=txtcedex]").val($(".lbcodex", $(this).closest("tr")).html());    
            return false;    
        });    
    </script>
```